# Using color of `Geom.hline` as aesthetic in Gadfly

Tags: julia, gadfly

In Gadfly, I am trying to color horizontal lines based on data. But since color of `Geom.hline` is not an aesthetic, but only an argument, my approach fails. How can I pass color form the data to the color argument?

**My attempt:**

```
using DataFrames, Gadfly

test = DataFrame(y = [1,2], group = ["a", "b"])
p = plot(test, yintercept = :y, color=:group, Geom.hline)
```

**Desired behavior:**

Two horizontal lines with two different colors (colored by `group`).

**Actual behavior:**

Two horizontal lines with the same color, warning message `The following aesthetics are mapped, but not used by any geometry: color`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `color` argument to `Geom.hline` rather than to the `plot` function. As an example:

```
using DataFrames, Gadfly


test = DataFrame(y=[1, 2], group=["a", "b"])
p = plot(test, yintercept=:y, Geom.hline(color=["red", "blue"]))
```

This gives me the following result:
[image: Gadfly plot]
In your case you would have to map your groups against colors